# Oracle: how to find a maximum underscore in a column?

Tags: sql, string, oracle, group-by, max

There are data in this column that I need to know the maximum underscore it has.

For example,

```
Column A:
1_2_10_148880_148881, 
1_11_15_3,
1_11_15_5_521_2
```

result is 5
The last data has the maximum underscore in column A.

What is the query for oracle to find the result? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with
  t (a) as (
    select '1_2_10_148880_148881' from dual union all
    select '1_11_15_3'            from dual union all
    select '1_11_15_5_521_2'      from dual
  )
select nvl(max(length(translate(a, '_' || a, '_'))), 0) as max_underscore
from   t
;

MAX_UNDERSCORE
--------------
             5
```

`translate` will replace every underscore with an underscore, and every other character from the input string to "nothing" (therefore just deleting it). So, what's left after `translate` is just the underscores from each string.

Then take the length of the resulting string (that's the same as the number of underscores in the original string), then take the `max`, and the `nvl` at the end is for the case when none of the strings had any underscores. In those cases, `translate` will return `null`, and alas the length of `null` is `null`, not 0. `nvl` fixes that.

Answer (score 2):

String functions may be more efficient than a regex for this simple task. The difference between the number of characters in the column, and the numbers of characters after removing the underscores gives you the result that you want:

```
select max(length(columna) - length(replace(columna, '_', ''))) max_no_underscore
from mytable
```

Comment: Agree regular expression is expensive

Comment: Alas, if a string has no underscores in it, the result of `replace` will be null, and so will be its length, and then the result of subtraction. If at least one string does have an underscore, that won't matter; but if none of the inputs has underscores in it, this will return `null` when - one would guess - the OP would like it to return 0.

Answer (score 1):

Use `regexp_count()`:

```
select max(regexp_count(a, '_'))
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7cd1c43fbaa1f1586714fc8798b48200) is a db<>fiddle